# Regex matching Text with Square Brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Using javascript I need to get the text and tokens from string like:

```
"type":"homePhone","means":"$[createJohnRequest.contactInfo[type=homePhone].means]"
```

Such that a regex will return:

```
$[createJohnRequest.contactInfo[type=homePhone].means]
```

I have a few attempts at this but none that work:

```
/(\$\[(.*?]))/g
```

will return: $[createJohnRequest.contactInfo[type=homePhone]

```
/(\$\[(.*]))/g
```

This works in the above case but is way too greedy for a case like:

```
{"firstName":"$[user.firstName]","userName":"$[user.username1]","details":
{"description":"this is $[user.username1] the $[user.username2] text th $[user.username3] 
at conta$[user.username4]ins the terms we want to find. $[final.object]"}}
```

Ideally I want a single regex to match both in multiline text:

```
some text here $[some.value.here]bunch of noisy text in between here
some more text here$[some.value[index]goes.here]some more noise here
```

$[some.value.here] and $[some.value[index].goes.here]

Anyone have any ideas to point me in the right direction?

I am leaning toward using $[some token]$ instead which is pretty simple to capture.

Comment: Aren't the given examples valid JSON? Can't you first parse it into a JavaScript object, and then perhaps loop through each attribute individually?

Comment: Any good reason not to parse it using JSON.parse (I noticed too late that @Katana314 asked the same)

Comment: To explain, regular expressions are simply the **wrong tool** for this job - since you can have nested square brackets (like in your first example), parsing such a string would require some sort of recursion which is not really possible to do well with regex alone.

Comment: @fstantis: That's true for most cases, but in the first example, rather than using the tree structure to find the end, you could just find the ] closest to the end of the string. (end with `\]$`)But, as I mentioned, that only works if you're looking at it as a JSON object, rather than a JSON string.

Comment: JS doesn't support recursion construct in regex. That's a shame. Would it kill Microsoft to do this right?

Comment: @sln That's not MS's fault. It'd rather be W3C's fault... But yes, JS's regexes are shamefully weak compared to what's possible out of the box in other languages. An answer to this question would be trivial with a better regex flavor.

Comment: You could use XRegExp and [the recursive addon](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#matchRecursive).

Comment: The snippets used for the question are taken out of context of a much larger problem. We never know what the body will look like - ever. The easiest way to solve it is to JSON.stringify the body and do a simple search and replace against it. The only rub is that we support JSONPath so the tokens we replace can get tricky. MS has nothing to do with the problem - it is a node.js app.

Comment: What is the maximum nesting depth of the square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this, as long as the bracket nesting level is limited to two:

```
/\$\[(\[.*]|.)*?\]/g
```

In English:

```
a dollar sign followed by 
a bracketed sequence whose content is
    any number of occurrences of 
        either 
            a bracketed subsequence whose content is anything
            or something else
```

See http://regexr.com/39iht.

If you want to support deeper nesting, I suggest you write a little function to build the regexp for you, so you don't go insane:

```
function make_regexp(level) {
    var build = "\\[.*?]";
    while (level--) {
        build = "(\\[" + build + "]|.)*?";
    }
    return RegExp("\\$" + build, "g");
}

> make_regexp(3)
/\$(\[(\[(\[.*]|.*)*?]|.*)*?]|.*)*?/g
```